# How to return var parameter in Delphi ASM

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm far from having knowledge about ASM, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have this function:

```
function SwapDWord(const AValue: DWORD): DWORD;
asm
  BSWAP EAX
end;
```

How would I convert it to a procedure in ASM:

```
procedure SwapDWordVar(var AValue: DWORD);
asm
  // ???
end;
```

I do not want to use `AValue := SwapDWord(AValue);` which I could. I want to do this in ASM.

I tried many silly things by looking at system.pas and tried to understand which register(s) to use. but nothing worked. It always return back the original `AValue`.

Comment: Why would you want to change what you already have? A function is far better design for this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, That was for learning purposes. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Of course not, but if you were planning on doing this for real you ought to know that it will make your code worse

Comment: I have a code like: `dw:=a; if condition then dw:=SwapDWord(dw); ... dw:=b; if condition then dw:=SwapDWord(dw); ...` etc... I wanted to do something like: `dw:=a; SwapDWordIf(dw, condition); dw:=b; SwapDWordIf(dw, condition);` I will do it in other way maybe `dw := SwapDWordIf(a, condition);` but I just wanted to learn how it's done in ASM.

Comment: Premature optimization, for sure.

Comment: Write the desired code in Pascal first and compile it, then study the resulting ASM code that is generated by the compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible variant:

```
procedure SwapDWordVar(var AValue: DWORD);
asm
  mov edx, [eax]
  bswap edx
  mov [eax], edx
end;
```

You might find useful Guido Gybels [articles](http://www.guidogybels.eu/asmch2.html)

Comment: This is the exact code I used! except I did not used the brackets on the eax register. can you explain what they mean?

Comment: `Var` argument stores address of variable. So `eax` contains address of variable, not its value. `[eax]` uses that address and takes value.

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
procedure SwapDWordVar(var AValue: DWORD);
asm
  mov edx, dword ptr [AValue]
  bswap edx
  mov dword ptr [AValue], edx
end;
```

Note that this version will compile and work for both Win32 and Win64.

But note that it won't be faster than `AValue := SWapDWord(AValue)` since most of the time will be spent calling the function, not accessing the memory.

Comment: [Error] Unit1.pas(57): Invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: Does `bswap` operate with memory? AFAIK, only with register

Comment: Yes, fixed. I didn't try to compile it. But silly question anyway. I've put a x64 compatible code version too.